# How to create common class for third-party API requests in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am creating NestJS application where I am making third-party API requests. For that I have to write the same thing inside every function in order to get the data.

To make things non-repeating, how can I write on common class that has API request based on GET or POST request and send the response so that I can use that class in every function.

Below is my code:

**subscribe.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SubscribeService {
constructor(@InjectModel('Subscribe') private readonly model:Model<Subscribe>,
            @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager:Cache,
            private httpService: HttpService){}

 async addSubscriber(subscriberDto:SubscribeDto){
     
    const url = 'https://track.cxipl.com/api/v2/phone-tracking/subscribe';  
    const headersRequest = {
        'content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authkey': process.env.AUTHKEY
    };

    try{

        const resp = await this.httpService.post(url,subscriberDto,{ headers: headersRequest }).pipe(
            map((response) => {

                if(response.data.success == true){
                     const data = new this.model(subscriberDto);
                    // return data.save();
                    const saved = data.save();
                    if(saved){
                        const msgSuccess = {
                                         "success":response.data.success,
                                         "status":response.data.data.status
                                       }
                        return msgSuccess;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    const msgFail = {"success":response.data.success}
                    return msgFail;
                }
            }),
          );
        return resp;
    }
    catch(err){
        return err;
    }
}

 async getLocation(phoneNumber:PhoneNumber){
   
    try{
        
        const location = await this.cacheManager.get<Coordinates>(phoneNumber.phoneNumber);
       
        if(location){
            return location; 
        }
        else{
         
        const resp = await axios.post('https://track.cxipl.com/api/v2/phone-tracking/location',phoneNumber,{headers:{
            'content-Type': 'application/json',
            'authkey': process.env.AUTHKEY
        }});
       
        const msg:Coordinates = {
                                  "location":resp.data.data.location,
                                  "timestamp":resp.data.data.timestamp
                                }
        await this.cacheManager.set<Coordinates>(phoneNumber.phoneNumber,msg, { ttl: 3600 });
        return msg;
        }
     }
     catch(err){
        console.log(err); 
        return err;
     }
   }
}
```

As in above code in both function `addSubscriber()` and `getLocation()` I need to hit the API repeatedly and add request headers again and again is there any way so that I can create one separate class for request and response and utilize in my service.

How can I achieve desired the result?

Comment: I would suggest creating an HTTP `client` instance to set basic stuff like *base url* and general *headers* (like API key). I like to use [GOT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) for my HTTP client. Check this doc from creating client instance https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/HEAD/documentation/10-instances.md

Comment: How can I do that do you have some reference or can you tell me in code.

Answer (score 0):

To create a common class for making third-party API requests in NestJS, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new file in your NestJS project to store the common class.
   For example, you could create a file called api.service.ts in the
   src/common directory.
2. In the file, create a new class called ApiService that will be responsible for making the API requests. This class should have a
   constructor that injects the necessary dependencies, such as the
   HttpService provided by NestJS.

   ```
   import { HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

   @Injectable()
   export class ApiService {
     constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}
   }
   ```
3. Add methods to the ApiService class for each type of API request you want to make. For example, you might have a get() method for making GET requests, a post() method for making POST requests, and so on. Each method should accept the necessary parameters for making the request (such as the URL and any query parameters or request body), and use the HttpService to make the request.

   ```
   import { HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

   @Injectable()
   export class ApiService {
      constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

      async get(url: string, params?: object): Promise<any> {
        return this.httpService.get(url, { params }).toPromise();
      }

      async post(url: string, body: object): Promise<any> {
        return this.httpService.post(url, body).toPromise();
      }
    }
   ```
4. Inject the ApiService wherever you need to make API requests. For example, you might inject it into a service or a controller, and use the methods of the ApiService to make the actual API requests.

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
   import { ApiService } from './api.service';

   @Injectable()
   export class SomeService {
     constructor(private readonly apiService: ApiService) {}

     async getData(): Promise<any> {
       return this.apiService.get('https://some-api.com/endpoint');
     }
   }
   ```

This is just one way you could create a common class for making third-party API requests in NestJS. You can customize the ApiService class to meet the specific needs of your application